# Swift 4 / Xcode 9.3 / iOS - Catch The file "x" couldn’t be opened because there is no such file with String(contentsOf: url)

Tags: swift, string, try-catch

**Swift 4 / Xcode 9.3 / iOS**

I'm using **String(contentsOf: url)** and in some cases I get an error because the file referenced by the URL doesn't exist.  I want to handle that specific error case.

I know I can check to see if the file exists first, but I want to handle the error case instead.

Right now I am doing:

```
let data = try String(contentsOf: url)
```

Up until now I've been catching all errors, with something like:

```
do {
    let data = try String(contentsOf: url)
    //<other code here>
} catch let error {
    fatalError("bad error: \(error)")
}
```

When the specific file I'm trying to pull from (from the give URL) doesn't exist, I get an error like this:

```
bad error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “whatever.json” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/myname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6529F22A-5234-49D7-9BB3-B9C71474CC53/data/Containers/Data/Application/005C1F55-07E8-4CF4-86FD-2F00B1144FD4/Documents/whatever.json, NSUnderlyingError=0x608000058180 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
```

How do I catch this error separately so I can handle it separately from other errors?  I've tried **CocoaError.fileNoSuchFile** and several in the POSIX error domain.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, so I've been fighting this for awhile, and as soon as I posted, I ended up solving it.

the answer is **CocoaError.fileReadNoSuchFile**.  I kept trying **CocoaError.fileNoSuchFile**.

So here's the answer:

```
do {
    let data = try String(contentsOf: url)
    //<other code here>
} catch CocoaError.fileReadNoSuchFile {
    print("CAUGHT IT!")
} catch let error {
    fatalError("bad error: \(error)")
}
```

Thanks!